# ggplot - how to easily draw tangents?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Imagine we have the following ellipse:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot() + 
    geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 30, y0 = 6, a = 2, b = 20, angle = 1.5)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-20, 55))
```

I am looking for an ***easy***, preferrably already existing way to draw tangents to this ellipse.

I am not looking for a way to do it manually because I could calculate them myself, but the purpose of this question is rather to see if anyone knows an already existing function from one of the hundreds of ggplot2 extension packages which would be able to do this automatically, or with just a little tweaking, but not with outright manual explicit calculation of tangents.

So, something like `geom_tangent` which already exists from before and could be added to the plot.

Does anything like this exist?

Edit: tangent needs to come from the origin of the plot, but it would be nice if the user can also specify the beginning of the tangent.

Comment: i don't think there is any function in ggplot2 or other packages that can automatically draw tangents to an ellipse.

Comment: Did you try to calculate using `# slope of the tangent at (x, y)
m <- -a^2/b^2 * sin(angle)/cos(angle)` and then `# y-intercept of the tangent
b <- y - m*x`  which can be plugged into ` + geom_abline(intercept = b, slope = m, color = "red", lwd=1.5)` between `geom_ellipse()` and `scale_x_continuous()` here a, b, angle, x and y  are from your code: `geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 30, y0 = 6, a = 2, b = 20, angle = 1.5))`

Comment: OP, 1) what do mean by "do it manually" here?  I'm wondering how any `geom_tangent` function could even work practically-speaking.  2) What do you mean by the "tangent needs to come from the origin of the plot"?  There's only going to be 2 tangents for any ellipse that pass through the origin (I believe).